# Is there a way to calculate working hours in excel

Tags: excel

I have data as given below and to calculate the exact time that is spent by an agent in this, with respect to connection,re connection time and disconnection time. This needs to be done for nearly 1000 agents and in excel either using excel/VBA.

```
EMP ID  Connection/Reconnection/Disconnection time      Time Stamp
ABCD        CONNECTED                                   3/30/2020 11:11
ABCD        DISCONNECTED                                3/30/2020 11:25
ABCD        RECONNECTED                                 3/30/2020 11:40
ABCD        DISCONNECTED                                3/30/2020 18:20
ABCD        RECONNECTED                                 3/30/2020 19:21
ABCD        DISCONNECTED                                3/30/2020 20:40
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide how the data is displayed in your worksheet? You should be able to do something with basic algebra if each connection is in a separate cell.

Comment: Melysa, The data is displayed in the same way as mentioned above i.e Connected time is in Row2 and other data points is in subsequent rows and need to do for nearly 1500 agents.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A$7="ABCD")*($B$2:$B$7="DISCONNECTED")*$C$2:$C$7))-SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A$7="ABCD")*($B$2:$B$7={"CONNECTED","RECONNECTED"})*$C$2:$C$7))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you reply, this really works for one person however need to do this for 1500 agents, so should i apply this 1500 times or is there a work around. Thanks

Comment: @samirsikri You can create distinct list of your agents and then replace static part of `($A$2:$A$7="ABCD")` with cell reference in formula.

Comment: Thank you so much. Really Appreciate your help.